# Jquery allow cursor to progress before document.ready function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In my project i want the cursor to progress state before document ready function and after the entire page is rendered it need to change the cursor to default state.

```
 (function($) {
    $('body').css('cursor','progress');  
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').css('cursor','progress'); }
```

This my code can anyone please help me out

Comment: It looks like you're setting the the same CSS twice

Comment: sorry (function($) {
    $('body').css('cursor','progress');  
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').css('cursor','progress'); }

Comment: sorry (function($) {
    $('body').css('cursor','progress');  
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').css('cursor','default'); }                                      It could be like this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you could do is something like this add a css rule for the body cursor

```
<style>
html {
  cursor: progress;
}
<style>
```

then just change the cursor again when page finish rendering all the contents.

```
$(window).on('load',function() {
    $('html').css('cursor','default'); 
}
```

Comment: Yeah thnak you but it doesnot show that loading symbol ...I want the loading symbol until the browser is loading

Answer (score 2):

At first, declare CSS style on head tag for force the cursor to waiting.

```
<style>
html {
  cursor: progress;
}
<style>
```

Next, use JQuery to change cursor to default after content load.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('html').css('cursor','default'); 
}
```

Good luck !

Comment: Yeah thnak you but it doesnot show that loading symbol ...I want the loading symbol until the browser is loading